# How do you reference APEX Application Items in Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I am creating a BEFORE DELETE trigger to insert records into an archive table that are deleted through an APEX form on another table. I want to update two columns "UPDATED_BY" and "UPDATED"_DATE" based on the SYSDATE and :APP_USER (APEX Application Item). I'm getting an error related to the :APP_USER (PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'APP_USER'). Is there a specific syntax I have to use to reference APEX app items when creating the trigger?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "ARCHIVE_DELETED_RECORDS" 
BEFORE
delete on "RECORD_TABLE"
for each row
begin
INSERT INTO DELETED_RECORD_TABLE (
    STAGING_ID,
    SOURCE_FILE_ID,
    DELETION_DATE,
    DELETED_BY,
    DELETED_FROM)
SELECT
    STAGING_ID,
    SOURCE_FILE_ID,
    SYSDATE,
    :APP_USER,
    'Record Table 1'
FROM RECORD_TABLE
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "ARCHIVE_DELETED_RECORDS" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Also see this post regarding triggers from 12c https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `V()` function to refer directly to APEX bind variables like `:APP_USER` in a database trigger, or really in any PL/SQL outside of APEX. APEX also generally uses **package state** to store **global variables** which need to be accessed externally. [See here for some discussion](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2014/02/dont-always-call-v/).

In your case, instead of `:APP_USER`, you could use either `V('APP_USER')` or `APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER`. [Documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Global-Variables.html#GUID-5164592B-6864-4E2B-8DE3-64B463687A41).

Note that if records are deleted from your table outside of APEX (for example, by a DBA running `delete from RECORD_TABLE`), the DELETED_BY field will be null. So you might want something like:

```
COALESCE(V('APP_USER'), SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), USER)
```

To prefer the APEX user if that's available, or the OS user if that's available, or finally the current schema user if nothing else is available.